# Setting up Jenkins for a multi-app android project

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jenkins-plugins

Project folder structure

```
.git
app_1
app_2
app_3
app_4
```

I am configuring Jenkins for app_1 android project. `settings.gradle` file for app_1 looks like the following

```
include ':app', '..:app_2', '..:app_3', '..:app_4'
```

Now, upon building the project on Jenkins I am getting the following error.
[image]

Also, I tried building the app by by changing my `settings.gradle` file to following:

```
include ':app', ':app_2', ':app_3', ':app_4'
```

But this causes the Android Studio Gradle build to fail.

Answer (score 0):

The first error you mentioned is because of the module's name('..:app_2') you used in settings.gradle. It contains chracters '..'. Remove this and it will not complain about this error.

For second error you have not mentioned the error you are getting. Share the error log and also build.gradle of root project and module 'app_1'.